# How to execute shell commands interactively in Ruby and get the result

Tags: ruby, linux, shell

There are two tasks.

1. send text from stdin
2. Get the last output from stdout

This is the process required by commands such as "doveadm pw". How do I perform this in Ruby?
The following code did not work. I can interact with it, but cannot get the final output.

**code**

```rb
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

password = "aaaaaa"

PTY.spawn("sudo doveadm pw -s CRAM-MD5") do |input, output, pid|
  str = input.expect(/Enter new password:/)
  puts str
  output.puts "#{password}"
  str = input.expect(/Retype new password:/)
  puts str
  output.puts "#{password}"
  str = input.expect(/^.+CRAM-MD5.+\w+$/)
  puts str
end
```

**Result**

```
Enter new password:
 
Retype new password:
 
{CRAM-MD5}5 // Failing
```

Comment: Tip: Use separate arguments to avoid shell nonsense and escaping issues, as in `spawn("sudo", "doveadm", "pw", ...)`

Comment: Tip: `puts x` is equivalent to `puts "#{x}"` with a lot less clutter.

Comment: Tip: If you don't care about surrounding junk, `/CRAM\-MD5/` is sufficient, or `/\bCRAM-MD5/b/` if you're expecting some kind of "break" (`\b`) on either side of it.

Comment: It's worth dumping out the exact string you're getting, as in `p str`, to look for any irregular characters in there.

Answer (score 0):

It worked.
The key point was to load the IO after all interactions were completed.

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

password = "aaaaaa"

PTY.spawn("sudo doveadm pw -s CRAM-MD5") do |input, output, pid|
  str = input.expect(/Enter new password:/)
  p str
  output.puts password
  str = input.expect(/Retype new password:/)
  p str
  output.puts password
  begin
    until input.eof?
      str = input.gets.chomp
      p str if str.match?(/CRAM-MD5/) 
    end
  rescue Errno::EIO
  ensure
    Process.wait pid
  end
end
```